# When do permutations fixing a set of elements fix another element?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be a group of permutations of $X$. I'm interested in the relation that holds between $x\in X$ and $Y\subseteq X$ iff $g(x) = x$ for all $g\in G$ s.t. $g(y) = y$ for all $y\in Y$. Is there a standard name for this relation, and is there a good reference for learning more about its properties?

Comment: The only thing that spings to mind is that, if $|Y|=1$ with $Y=\{y\}$, and $X = {\rm Fix}({\rm Stab}_G(y))$, then $X$ is a block for the action of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the elements from $X$ that are stabilized by the intersection of all stabilizers of elements from $Y$.

That is, you are asking for: $$\operatorname{Fix}\mathopen{}\left(\bigcap_{y\in Y}G_y\right)\mathclose{}$$ using the notational conventions that I know of.

$G_y$ is the set of all $g\in G$ s.t. $g(y)=y$. It's automatically a subgroup of $G$, and it is called the "stabilizer of $y$".

By intersecting over all $y\in Y$, you get the subgroup of $G$ that fixes *all* the $y\in Y$.

When $H$ is a subset of the group $G$ that is acting on $X$, then $\operatorname{Fix}(H)$ is the set of all elements in $X$ that $H$ fixes.

So more closely answering what I think is your question, suppose you have a set $Y\subset X$. For some $x$, $x\in\operatorname{Fix}\mathopen{}\left(\bigcap_{y\in Y}G_y\right)\mathclose{}$, and for other $x$, $x\not\in\operatorname{Fix}\mathopen{}\left(\bigcap_{y\in Y}G_y\right)\mathclose{}$. I don't know that there is specific standard vocabulary for this that is more concise.